# can phpunit-skelgen used in phpstorm IDE? how?

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm

can phpunit-skelgen used in phpstorm IDE? how?

I am working this way now:

php phpunit-skelgen.phar generate-test Logger C:/Wnmp/html/linhe/tools/logger.php LoggerTest  C:/Wnmp/html/linhe/phpunitTest/loggerTest.php

is there better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, skelgen is not included in PHPStorm (starting from version 7). See https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Creating+PHPUnit+Tests+in+PhpStorm. If you need using it, try configuring it as external tool (Settings/External Tools)

Answer (score 0):

External tool configuration in phpstorm 8.0.2:

```
Program: /home/myhome/projects/myproject/vendor/bin/phpunit-skelgen
Parameters: generate-test $SelectedText$ $FileDirRelativeToProjectRoot$/$FileName$ $SelectedText$Test tests/$FileDirRelativeToProjectRoot$/$FileNameWithoutExtension$Test.php
```

You have to select class name and then you can use this external tool